# How to make anonymous all quiz submissions?

Tags: quiz

I am trying out the quiz module and would like to be able to anonymize all quiz submissions, is this possible? Perhaps though a `query_alter` hook?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to accomplish.  You want users to authenticate before taking the quiz, but then hide who took it?  do you want to change this in the database so nobody will ever know or just hid this from specific users?

Comment: Yes I cannot tie uids to answers as a strict requiremnt. Not in the DB and not anywhere. I was able to accomplish this by implementing hook_quiz_result_presave .. and altering form['uid'] = 0.